# TableViewCell Long press no longer detected after switching datasource swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I was curious as why changing the datasource disables the long press in swift. I am currently using XCode 8 Version 5. I haven't found a solution as to what could be causing yet. Does the longpress need to know about the other source as well or if I made changes to it?

Code Below

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var changeDataBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var ChangeBtn: UIButton!
var longPressRecognizer:UILongPressGestureRecognizer!
var refresh: UIRefreshControl!
var testList:[String] = []
var altList:[String] = ["Test Alt Cell 1","Test Alt Cell 2","Test Alt Cell 3","Test Alt Cell 4"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return self.testList.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = testList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var i = 1
    while i < 6{
        testList.append("Test Cell \(i)")
        i+=1
    }
    refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refresh)

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

}
func refreshData() {
    // Code to refresh table view
    doInBackGround()
}

func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        if tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) != nil {
            print("Long Press Detected")
            // your code here, get the row for the indexPath or do whatever you want
        }
    }
}


func doInBackGround(){
    testList.removeAll()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("Refreshing Data Source")
        var temp:[String] = []
        var i = 1
        while i < 9{
            temp.append("New Test Cell \(i)")
            i+=1
        }
        self.testList = temp

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refresh.endRefreshing()
    }
}


@IBAction func changeDataSrc(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Changed Data Source")
    refresh.beginRefreshing()
    testList = altList
    tableView.reloadData()
    refresh.endRefreshing()
    //let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
    //self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}






override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fix was removing everything from `longPress`

So it Look like this:

`func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Long Press Activated")
    }`

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "change the data source?"

It looks to me like you're changing the array that feeds your data source, but not changing your table view's `dataSource` property.

You've got code that is changing the array that feeds your `tableView(_, cellForRowAt:)` from the background. That's a bad idea, and likely to cause side-effects up to and including crashing. You should move the assignment to `self.testList` to inside your call to `DispatchQueue.main.async` so the array is changed from the main thread. I don't know if that's the cause of your current problem, but it will likely cause SOME kind of problem.

### EDIT:

Your code used to look like this:

```
func doInBackGround(){
    testList.removeAll()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("Refreshing Data Source")
        var temp:[String] = []
        var i = 1
        while i < 9{
            temp.append("New Test Cell \(i)")
            i+=1
        }
        self.testList = temp
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refresh.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Instead, do it like this:

```
func doInBackGround(){
    testList.removeAll()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("Refreshing Data Source")
        var temp:[String] = []
        var i = 1
        while i < 9{
            temp.append("New Test Cell \(i)")
            i+=1
        }
        //Once temp has been built, send a message to the main thread 
        //to reload the table view.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refresh.endRefreshing()
            self.testList = temp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct about changing the assignment, but then it won't be reachable since its inside the `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`. But it isn't the source of the problem. By Changing the datasource, I meant changing the array that feeds the data source (In this case to altList). I also agree it may have side-effects, but that only happens when they user pulls on the tableView to refresh. In this case there's a button that switches to altList.

Comment: Yes, it will be reachable. Why did you edit your question and remove the code we were talking about? I could edit your code in my answer and show you what a I was talking about, but it's gone. Off to extract your pre-edit code...

Comment: Sorry, I edited so it was a bit more readable and relevant to the question I was asking. I'll put it back if that helps